# Understanding Angular Shared service

Tags: angular, service, components, observable, behaviorsubject

I want to keep total amount of my component updated as it's changing, and I'm wondering is this right:

I have a `shared.service.ts` which is injected into my component so it looks like this (my shared service):

```
shared.service.ts

private sumEmit= new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

public updateValues() {
this.sum= 0;
this.sum+= +(price*quant).toFixed(2);
this.sumEmit.next(this.sum);
}
```

Method to get total amount also in service:

```
 getTotal(): BehaviorSubject<number> {
    return this.sumEmit;
  }
```

So, every time `updateValues()` method is called, it will emit value of sum, that's right?

And in my component which need to retreive value everytime value is changed I did this:

```
mycomponent.component.ts
```

First of all I injected shared service, after that in `ngOnInit` life cycle hool I wrote:

```
// simple variable to hold value from service

total : number;


ngOnInit() 
{
    this.total = this.SharedService.getTotal();
}
```

Does this mean that my value will be up to date everytime total amount is changed?

Most confusing part for me is that I called this method only once in a `ngOnInit` which is rendered when component is opened, but value is kept updated.. Could anyone explain me this please? How come variable in my component is aware when value is changed in service? Which part is responsible for that?

Thanks

Comment: Where  do you use `total` property?

Comment: @yurzui I use it on one of my components to display current value of total amount, there is an array in shared service and everytime I add value or someone else in that array I'm calling method updateValues which emits total and I display it on few of components whenever I need it..

Comment: Are you using it like `{{total}}` or `{{total | async}}`?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro I updated my answer with some of the question you asked in comments. I hope it's clearer now. Let me know if there is something you do not understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How come variable in my component is aware when value is changed in
>   service?

You are using BehaviourSubject, This means that new subscribers will always get the last value emitted synchronously.

> Which part is responsible for that?

**`this.sumEmit.next(this.sum);`**

Comment: @Sajeetharan why it works if I don't use .subscribe in my component, anyway component know for new value, how ?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro that is the functionality of using behavioursubject. it is handled within the core itsef. if you return observable only you need to subscribe, since you are returning a subject this should work

Comment: if you want to subscribe in your component return return this.sumEmit; an observable and call subscribe()

Comment: @Sajeetharan Thanks for help, so if I want to subsribe i can change BehaviorSubject to Observable  ? What is better, what you think?

Comment: you should use observable here as i see and understand the difference betwen the two from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/behaviorsubject-vs-observable

Answer (score 1):

> So, every time `updateValues()` method is called, it will emit value of
>   sum, that's right?

Yes, that's right.

> Does this mean that my value will be up to date every time total amount
>   is changed?

Yes.

> How come variable in my component is aware when value is changed in
>   service?

Because `BehaviorSubject` extends from `Subject` which extends from `Observable` (and implements `SubscriptionLike`). `Observable`s work in a way that every time a new value is set to the variable by the publishers (`this.sumEmit.next(this.sum)` in this case) all subscribers are notified with the new value.

You can read more about this at [Angular-Observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables) and [ReactiveX-Observable](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html)

> Which part is responsible for that?

This one

```
this.sumEmit.next(this.sum);
```

**Additional notes**

- Why it works if we do not use `.subscribe`?

Because the `value` property can be accessed at any time, a distinctive characteristic of `BehaviorSubject`s (see this [discussion](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/758)). This is different from `Subject` or `Observable`, where you start getting values only if you subscribe to their streams.

We can access the value using the `getValue` method, i.e.: `let theValue = this.SharedService.getTotal().getValue()`. Also, if we assign the `BehaviorSubject` to a variable (let's call it `val`) and use this variable, i.e. with the [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe, the value is automatically extracted by this pipe and you'll see the UI updated automatically, without needing to subscribe to the stream (the pipe does this for you). For example:

```
// component.ts
this.val = this.SharedService.getTotal(); // val is a `BehaviorSubject`

// component.html
{{ val | async }}
```

- If I want to subscribe can I change `BehaviorSubject` to `Observable`?

You don't need to change to Observable in order to subscribe. You can subscribe to `BehaviorSubject` as well, in the same way you would do with an `Observable`. In case you want to get the `BehaviorSubject` as `Observable` you just need to do: `const myObservable: Observable = myBehaviorSubject.asObservable();`

- Which one is better: `BehaviorSubject` or `Observable`?

We can not say one is better than the other, they just behave differently in some aspects. You need to apply one or the other depending on the situation. In general, `BehaviorSubjects` are useful for representing "values over time". For instance, an event stream of birthdays is a Subject, but the stream of a person's age would be a `BehaviorSubject` (See *BehaviorSubject* section at [RxJS-Overview](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html)).

**Further readings**

- [BehaviorSubject vs Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/behaviorsubject-vs-observable)
- [Any downside to always using BehaviorSubject instead of Subject (RxJs\Angular)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49504713/any-downside-to-always-using-behaviorsubject-instead-of-subject-rxjs-angular)
- [Understanding rxjs BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject and AsyncSubject](https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0)

Comment: I did not do that part with .subscribe and it works, how come?

Comment: subscribe is not necesasry here